# Exclude 0 after decimal point

Tags: r, function

I want to exclude 0 after decimal point from my summary below
like if a value is

```
22.34
31.7
76.00
```

output should be

```
22.34
31.7
76
```

if there is zero after decimal point it should get excluded automatically

```
Median =round(quantile(data$column, type=4, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using regex :

```
x <- c(22.34, 31.7, 76.00, 75.10100)
sub('\\.0*$', '', x)
#[1] "22.34"  "31.7"   "76"     "75.101"
```

Here we remove 0's occurring at the end of the number after decimal places.

---

To apply this for multiple columns, we can use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
new_Tab <- summ_tab1 %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~sub('\\.0*$', '', .)))
```

Or in earlier version of `dplyr` use `mutate_all` :

```
new_Tab <- summ_tab1 %>% mutate_all(~sub('\\.0*$', '', .))
```

Comment: How i can use it int my summary code..?

Comment: @MohammadShoaib For which column do you want to apply this code? All the columns?

Comment: for all column i need to apply for

Comment: i want the output summary should exclude 0 after decimal places for every output

Comment: Check the updated answer to apply the function on every column in `summ_tab1`.

Comment: please explain how is it working for more understanding

Comment: @MohammadShoaib I added some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Using `prettyNum`.

```
dat$V1 <- prettyNum(dat$V1)

dat
#      V1
# 1 22.34
# 2  31.7
# 3    76
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(text="22.34
31.7
76.00")
```